# How to get the total number of apps and total numbers of downloads on google play

Tags: android

I can only get some of the information on media, and they are out of date. Is there any place I can find up to date data?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take a look at AppBrain.  You can find the answer to both your questions there.

http://www.appbrain.com/stats/number-of-android-apps